# Use semi-bold instead of boldface fonts in code listing syntax highlighting

Tags: listings

By default, LaTeX syntax highlighting for source code uses **bold** text for keywords. How can I instruct it to use semi-bold fonts instead. (This assumes, of course, that a semi-bold variety exists for a given font.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `keywordstyle` to set the appearance for keywords, for example `\bfseries` (normal bold) or `\sbweight` (semi-bold). This option can be set in `\lstset` to set the value for all subsequent listings or as an optional argument to a single `lstlisting` or `lstinputlisting` environment.

You can also consider using flexible columns to take advantage of the smaller width of semibold.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Python}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i in range(10):
   print i
\end{lstlisting}
\lstset{keywordstyle=\sbweight}
\begin{lstlisting}
for i in range(10):
   print i
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[keywordstyle=\itshape]
for i in range(10):
   print i
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible]
for i in range(10):
   print i
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]